# How to hide row if all visible cells in cell range are blank in VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am running some VBA macros in my Excel spreadsheet to help me eliminate irrelevant data from view to then allow me to export/copy a subset of the overall set of data I have.  My spreadsheet size is Columns(A:BN) and Rows(1:4693), which I would imagine is a decent size data set. Columns(A:G) will always remain visible.  I'm only interested in hiding what is in Columns(H:BN).

First, If I want to keep the column in view, I set the column value to "Y", then I click the 'Hide Columns" button. I do this by attaching this subroutine to a button:

```
Sub Hidecolumn()
Dim p As Range
    For Each p In Range("H1:BN1").Cells
        If p.Value = "N" Then
            p.EntireColumn.Hidden = True          
        End If
    Next p  
End Sub
```

This works perfectly.

I also have a "Show All Columns" button to have all of the hidden columns reappear, and I do this with:

```
Sub Unhidecolumn()
Dim p As Range
    For Each p In Range("H1:BN1").Cells
        If p.Value = "Y" Or p.Value = "N" Then
            p.EntireColumn.Hidden = False    
        End If
    Next p   
End Sub
```

Now that I have the columns I want, now I need to hide all of the unwanted rows. Each cell will have a "Y" in it if that row-column relationship exist. It will be blank if there is no relationship.  I want to hide all rows where all of the visible cells in the cell range are blank.  ALL CELLS in the cell range must be blank.

Once I've hidden all of the unwanted rows, then I can copy the remaining/visible data and copy it to a new workbook to share with others, because they only need the data relevant to them.

Finally, just like I am able to unhide all of the hidden columns, I need to also be able to unhide all of the hidden rows.

In the end, I want 4 buttons on my sheet.
1. Hide Columns
2. Unhide Columns
3. Hide Rows
4. Unhide Rows

I already have the first 2, now I need the last 2.  Please help.

UPDATE: SOLUTION - Thank you @K.Davis!

```
Sub HideRowsSecond()

    Dim srcRng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set srcRng = ws.Rows("5:" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim R As Range, hideRng As Range
    For Each R In srcRng
        If Application.CountA(R.Columns("H:BN").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = 0 Then
            If hideRng Is Nothing Then
                Set hideRng = R.EntireRow
            Else
                Set hideRng = Application.Union(hideRng, R.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next R

    If Not hideRng Is Nothing Then hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pre-built `CountA()` worksheet function to count the number of cells that have data in them. This count will return a value of `0` if the entire row is blank.

I would use `UsedRange` so you are not unnecessarily counting past your data. I would also union ranges to be hidden and hide them all at once, instead of one at a time for better performance.

```
Sub HideRows()

    Dim r As Range, hideRng As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        If Application.CountA(r.EntireRow) = 0 Then
            If hideRng Is Nothing Then
                Set hideRng = r.EntireRow
            Else
                Set hideRng = Application.Union(hideRng, r.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If not hideRng is nothing then hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

You don't need to overcomplicate the unhiding of the rows. This will unhide your rows without looping.

```
Sub UnHideRows()

    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

---

Thanks to Chris Neilsen pointing out that you may have only wanted to check if the visible columns had any data, you can use this in place of the first code:

```
Sub HideRows()

    Dim r As Range, hideRng As Range

    UnHideRows

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        If Application.CountA(r.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = 0 Then
            If hideRng Is Nothing Then
                Set hideRng = r.EntireRow
            Else
                Set hideRng = Application.Union(hideRng, r.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not hideRng Is Nothing Then hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

---

---

---

Per OP's response of only wanting to look in the visible rows between the columns of `H:BN`, you can use the following to accomplish this:

```
Sub HideRows()

    Dim srcRng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set srcRng = ws.Rows("1:" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    UnHideRows

    Dim r As Range, hideRng As Range
    For Each r In srcRng
        If Application.CountA(r.Columns("H:BN").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = 0 Then
            If hideRng Is Nothing Then
                Set hideRng = r.EntireRow
            Else
                Set hideRng = Application.Union(hideRng, r.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not hideRng Is Nothing Then hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

In this function, I went ahead and created a new Range variable `srcRng`, because using the `Columns()` function with `UsedRange` can sometimes cause issues. Since we are no longer using `UsedRange`, we are now finding the last use row with `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: I suspect the OP want to check only visible cells in a row (in case some columns are hidden),  in which case use Aggregate to do the count.  Otherwise,  good answer

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @chrisneilsen. I believe `Aggregate` can only be used to exclude hidden rows (not columns). I will post an edit shortly.

Comment: Thanks Chris Neilsen and K.Davis.  Please note that the entire row will never be completely blank.  As mentioned above, columns (A:G) will always have values in them.  I only want to evaluate the values in each visible row for columns (H:BN). Remember, I have already hidden all of the necessary columns at this point, so of the original 59 columns, it is possible that only 7 columns remain visible.  I only want to evaluate the values in the 7 visible columns for each row, and if those 7 visible columns are blank, then I want to hide that row and move the next row, and repeat until the end.

Comment: @jusrleb1 Take a look at the update at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs - thanks for the update.  One more issue, and this is my fault because I forgot to mention.  I do not want to evaluate Rows(1:4).  The row evaluation needs to start at Row 5, and then go to the end of the sheet.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs - I was able to edit your revised code and get it start at row 5.  
`Set srcRng = ws.Rows("5:" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`

I am now noticing that it does not evaluate the last row of the sheet.  How do I fix that?

Comment: @jusrleb1 Does the last row have a value in column A? The `1` in `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1)` refers to column A when it checks for the last row.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs It does not.  Use column D, it has a value in each row.  Changed it to a 4.  `Set srcRng = ws.Rows("5:" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)`.  Works perfectly!  Thank you.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs can you also help me with this last step: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943013/how-do-i-print-save-only-the-visible-columns-and-rows-to-an-xlsx-file-in-vba