# How do I print/save only the visible columns and rows to an XLSX file in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro-enabled spreadsheet that allows me to hide various columns and rows based on certain criteria I select and trigger on the sheet.

First I select the relevant columns by marking that column with a "Y", and hiding the remaining columns with a "N" with the following routine:

```
Sub Hidecolumn()
Dim p As Range

    For Each p In Range("H1:BN1").Cells
        If p.Value = "N" Then
            p.EntireColumn.Hidden = True


        End If
    Next p

End Sub
```

Please note that Columns("A:G") will always be visible.  Only Columns("H:BN") can be hidden based on the above.  This works perfectly.

Then, I will hide the the various rows that do not have a value in the remaining visible columns for Columns("H:BN"), which is 59 possible columns. If any column within that row has a value, then that row will remain visible.  If there are NO values in any of the visible columns for that row, then I hide that row. It is entirely possible that the 59 columns could reduce to 7. I do this with the following routine:

```
Sub HideRowsSecond()

    Module2.Unhiderow

    Dim srcRng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set srcRng = ws.Rows("5:" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim R As Range, hideRng As Range
    For Each R In srcRng
        If Application.CountA(R.Columns("H:BN").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = 0 Then
            If hideRng Is Nothing Then
                Set hideRng = R.EntireRow
            Else
                Set hideRng = Application.Union(hideRng, R.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next R

    If Not hideRng Is Nothing Then hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub
```

Please note that the starting row is Row("5"), and we use Column("D") as the counting column because it has a value in every cell down to the bottom of the data set.  This works perfectly.

Now that I have my desired data set, I need to save this visible data set to a new XLSX file that the user can name themselves and save in the directory of their choice.  The target range will begin with cell "C3" and we need to save however many visible columns there are to the right and however many visible rows there are down to the bottom of the data set.

Can someone please help me with this final step?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
Sub exportToFile()
    Dim rng As Range

    With ActiveSheet
      Set rng = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, .Columns.Count - 2).Offset(2, 2))
    End With

    rng.Select
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy

    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A" & Row & ":N" & Row).EntireRow.AutoFit
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ("c:\")
End Sub
```